# Trying to prove the derivative at a point is 0 using limit definition.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, proof-writing

I'm trying to prove that $g'(c)=0$ where $c\:\in\:\mathbb{R}$ and $g(x): \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$.

To go about this, I'm trying to show that $\lim_{x \to c} \frac{g(x)-g(c)}{x-c}=0$.

I've managed to prove that $\forall\: \epsilon> 0 , \exists \delta > 0$ s.t. $\forall x\:\in \: \mathbb{R}\setminus \{c\}, |x-c|\leq \delta \implies |\frac{g(x)-g(c)}{x-c}-0| < \epsilon$. Would this be sufficient proof?

Note at the end the inequality is $<$, rather than $\leq$. I'm not sure whether this makes a difference?

I would be grateful if anybody could tell me whether the proof is sufficient with $<$ rather than $\leq$, and, if so, why that is.

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: Note that $<$ implies $\leq$.

Comment: Could you say what $g$ is?

Comment: I don't know what g(x) is. I've instead been given that it satisfies the Holder condition. I'm meant to use this to show that it's differentiable at c with derivative = 0.

Comment: So is it perfectly valid to prove that the derivative is 0 in this way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is sufficient.  If $a<b$ then $a\leq b$ (since $a\leq b$ just means "$a<b$ or $a=b$").  So $\left|\frac{g(x)-g(c)}{x-c}-0\right| < \epsilon$ implies $\left|\frac{g(x)-g(c)}{x-c}-0\right| \leq \epsilon$ as well.  Thus it is still true that given $\epsilon$ and your choice of $\delta$, $0<|x-c|\leq \delta$ implies $\left|\frac{g(x)-g(c)}{x-c}-0\right| \leq \epsilon$.

(Actually, I'm surprised that you want $\leq$ instead of $<$.  The definition of limits is usually formulated with $<$, not with $\leq$, though it turns out the definitions are equivalent.)